# Issue with new MapKit MarkerAnnotationView in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, ios11

I'm having trouble with MKAnnotationView. I wrote the code embedded below to display my pin, which works, but I never EVER want the subtitle to show up, so I wrote the var subtitleVisibility: MKFeatureVisibility to .hidden, as shown in my code. Though it still shows up, just like if the subtitleVisibility was .adaptive ...
What's wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!
Flo!

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        guard let annotation = annotation as? Bike else { return nil }

        let identifier = "marker"
        var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView

        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
            as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = false
            view.markerTintColor = self.userBike.markerTintColor
            view.glyphImage = self.userBike.glyphImage
        }
        view.subtitleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibility.hidden
        view.animatesWhenAdded = true
        return view
    } else {
        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin-annotation")

        annotationView.animatesDrop = true
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `subtitleVisibility` is set to `false` it only stops the text from showing when the marker is not selected. When the marker is selected the subtitle will show.

[MKMarkerAnnotationView subtitleVisibility](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview/2873813-subtitlevisibility?language=objc) Documentation:

> The subtitle text is hidden when the marker is not selected. The text is shown when the marker is selected.

Comment: Oh, right, I thought it had the same behavior as titleVisibility (which can be hidden all the time, cf WWDC MapKit video), weird...